# Converting json into java object error UnrecognizedPropertyException

Tags: java

I have to make java object from my json file that looks like this:
{
"colors": ["red", "green", "blue"],
"isPrimary": true,
"rgb": {
"r": 255,
"g": 0,
"b": 0
}
}

I created class with parametrs that describes my file

```
public class Color {
    private List<String> colors;
    private boolean isPrimary;
    private HashMap<String,Integer> rgb = new HashMap<String,Integer>();


    public Color(){};
    public List<String> getColors() {
        return colors;
    }

    public void setColors(List<String> colors) {
        this.colors = colors;
    }

    public boolean isPrimary() {
        return isPrimary;
    }

    public void setPrimary(boolean primary) {
        isPrimary = primary;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getRgb() {
        return rgb;
    }

    public void setRgb(HashMap<String, Integer> rgb) {
        this.rgb = rgb;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Color{" +
                "colors=" + colors +
                ", isPrimary=" + isPrimary +
                ", rgb=" + rgb +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        String jsonStr = "{\r\n" +
                "  \"colors\": [\"red\", \"green\", \"blue\"],\r\n" +
                "  \"isPrimary\": true,\r\n" +
                "  \"rgb\": {\r\n" +
                "    \"r\": 255,\r\n" +
                "    \"g\": 0,\r\n" +
                "    \"b\": 0\r\n" +
                "  }\r\n" +
                "}";
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Color color = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, Color.class);
        System.out.println(color);
    }
```

I was following instruction but
Probably something is wrong

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "isPrimary" (class itstep.task_5.Color), not marked as ignorable (3 known properties: "colors", "primary", "rgb"])
 at [Source: (String)"{
  "colors": ["red", "green", "blue"],
  "isPrimary": true,
  "rgb": {
    "r": 255,
    "g": 0,
    "b": 0
  }
}";
```

Comment: Your JSON property key should be named as `primary` instead of `isPrimary`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that your JSON field name is `isPrimary`, but your Java field name is `primary`.

To fix this issue, you can either change the JSON field name to `primary` or add a `@JsonProperty` annotation to your Java field to specify that it should map to the `isPrimary` JSON field name:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class Color {
    private List<String> colors;
    @JsonProperty("isPrimary")
    private boolean primary;
    private HashMap<String, Integer> rgb = new HashMap<>();

    public Color() {}

    public List<String> getColors() {
        return colors;
    }

    public void setColors(List<String> colors) {
        this.colors = colors;
    }

    public boolean isPrimary() {
        return primary;
    }

    public void setPrimary(boolean primary) {
        this.primary = primary;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getRgb() {
        return rgb;
    }

    public void setRgb(HashMap<String, Integer> rgb) {
        this.rgb = rgb;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Color{" +
                "colors=" + colors +
                ", primary=" + primary +
                ", rgb=" + rgb +
                '}';
    }
}
```

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String jsonStr = "{\r\n" +
                "  \"colors\": [\"red\", \"green\", \"blue\"],\r\n" +
                "  \"isPrimary\": true,\r\n" +
                "  \"rgb\": {\r\n" +
                "    \"r\": 255,\r\n" +
                "    \"g\": 0,\r\n" +
                "    \"b\": 0\r\n" +
                "  }\r\n" +
                "}";
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Color color = objectMapper.readValue(jsonStr, Color.class);
        System.out.println(color);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Color{colors=[red, green, blue], primary=true, rgb={r=255, b=0, g=0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setter and getter have the wrong names. Jackson is trying to assing the value using setter methods in the format `set{fieldname}` such as `setIsPrimary`. But your setter is called `setPrimary`, and so the property "isPrimary" of your class  (a property is identified by a getter and setter with the same name) cannot be found. That is what the Exception is trying to tell you.

TL;DR:
rename your `setPrimary` method to `setIsPrimary`.